# How to propagate changes from Entity row to View row

Tags: oracle-adf

Normally, if we update an attribute in a View row, we can easily see the updated value in the Entity row as changes are propagated down the hierarchy.

My question is if we instead update an attribute on the Entity level, is there a way that we can get the new value on a current View row of a View object that was built using that Entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you update an attribute on EO level, it will automatically update the VO attribute as well. It goes both ways.

Seeing you are asking this makes me think you tried it and it didn’t look like working. If that’s the case, you are probably having a Partial Refresh problem in your screen. You can try using a partialTrigger.

Comment: You're right. I tried but it didn't work. As for the Partial Refresh problem. I tried to set an attribute on the VO level and the UI showed the new value. However, when I set the same attribute on the EO level, the UI couldn't show the new value. I don't think Partial Refresh is my issue. Besides, after setting the attribute on EO level, I did try to print out the value of the same attribute on VO level on the console and what I saw is still the old value.

Comment: Is your VO based on this EO? And if it so, is there a single EO or several EO's joined?